# Calling function object returned doesn't show same results? Python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why the calls to `f()()` not the same as `h=f()` then `h()`
when the id's are the same for `f()` and `h`?

Python program:

```
def f():
  c = [0]
  def g():
    c[0] += 1
    return c[0]
  return g

print (id(f()), id(f()))
print (f()(), f()())

h = f()
print (id(h))
print (h(), h())
```

Output:

```
140383530386568 140383530386568
1 1
140383530386568
1 2
```

**EDIT:**
and why does the value of `c` persist???

Comment: Because in the first case, you create the new function and call it on the fly, twice. The `c` as its free variable refers to two different objects. In the second case, you are calling the same function. The IDs happen to be the same because the interpreter reused the same memory location.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That seems to answer the question pretty well. I would recommend posting that as an answer.

Comment: On my.phone, can't do it justice

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I see! So the two functions created on the fly got garbage collected and hence the id's used for ```h``` happened to be the same? That is very clear now.  Please correct me if my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: Yes. And actually, it's because you also called `id`. If you had used `is` it would have been False.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your second question, the reason for the inner function remembering the value of `c` is due to a concept in python called *function closures*.

```
>>> def print_msg(msg):
...     def foo():
...         print(msg)
...     return foo
... 
>>> f = print_msg('hello')
>>> f()
hello
```

This value in the enclosing scope is remembered even when the variable goes out of scope or the function itself is removed from the current namespace.

You may view the contents of your function's closure by accessing it's `__closure__` hook: `f._closure__[0].cell_contents`.

---

To answer your first question, when you call `f()()` twice, you create and return the function *on the fly*. So each time the function is recreated with a fresh version `c`. The second time, when you assign it to a variable `h`, you keep a reference to the inner function, and so the value of `c` is retained because of why I mentioned earlier. So the second time you call that same function, `c[0]`'s value is incremented.

Comment: Just realized @Huang beat me to the punch. _Derp_.

Comment: @ChristianDean At the cost of sounding redundant. Added. :P

Answer (score 2):

There is a concept `closure` in python.

When you call `f`, the returned object contains an `__closure__` attribute.
You can check it by calling `h.__closure__`, and in your case you can get 
`c` by calling `h.__closure__[0].cell_contents`.

> A closure is function that retains the bindings of the free variables that exist when the function is defined, so that they can be used later when the function is invoked and the defining scope is no longer available. -- Fluent Python

Comment: I just did ```h.__closure__[0].cell_contents``` and it in fact display ```[3]``` like we would expect. But is there a way to see that it is associated with the name ```c```?

Comment: @Seoul Yeah. If you modify your function to `print(id(c))` each time the inner function is called, you can verify that.

Comment: @Seoul Yes. You can see the variables by calling `h.__code__.co_freevars`.